# Redesigning Ti SensorTag

Tags: sensors, bluetooth-lowenergy, circuit-diagram

This is my first question in Stackoverflow :)

I'm trying to make few modifications to the [Ti Sensortag](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_User_Guide) but I have few questions please:

1- is it possible to make the sensortags communicate with each-other without a gateway?
(lets Say I put Sensor1 in bedroom 1 and sensor 2 in bedroom 2 can I make them exchange readings without the need for a gateway?)

2- can I install a micro USB over the interface connector to be able to use a portable battery pack? ([photo of the interface connector](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/8/84/SensorTag_HW_with_arrows.png))

thanks

Comment: I would try the TI support forums they will be a better bet then here for this sort of question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get better more in depth responses on the TI support forums as Ifor has said.

However, I can tell you the answer to #1...  Regular bluetooth allows for things like piconets, but Low Energy does not.  With LE you have a client/server (master/slave) connection between two devices only.  It may be possible to modify the firmware on the sensortags to allow them to make connections to other sensortags, but then they'd have to give up whatever connection they currently had to do so.  The master devices can connect to multiple slave devices, but the slave device can only be connected to one master.

As the sensortags are currently designed, I think they only work as a slave (server) device.

Comment: The sensortag can be considered as just a board for the CC254x chip, and the software stack for that supports both peripheral and central roles (though maybe not at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

Press releases say that the new 4.1 spec allows for a single BLE device to act in both roles--central and peripheral eliminating the need for a gateway. A 4.1 update is, in theory, possible with 4.0 radio hardware like the SensorTag has. I personally haven't seen an example of this however and SensorTag processing resources may be a limiting factor to a dual role.

The Battery Pack connector breaks out VDD_EXT and GND and the SensorTag hardware schematic is available. Analysis by a hardware design engineer should be able to determine the suitability of a USB source powering option.
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_User_Guide

Comment: It's likely all that is needed is a small 3.3v or so regulator and a few bypass capacitors.